# Integral along closed contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, laurent-series

In the Laurent series, the coefficient

$$b_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(z)}{(z - z_0)^{-n + 1}}dz,\qquad\left(\, n = 1,2,\ldots\,\right)$$

collapses to zero when $f(z)$ is analytic in the neighbourhood of a point $z_0$ enclosed by a closed contour $C$.

Why isn't that the same for

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(z)}{(z - z_0)^{n + 1}}dz,\qquad\left(\, n = 0,1,2,\ldots\,\right)\,?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is analytic, the function $$\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{-n+1}} = f(z)(z-z_0)^{n-1}$$ is analytic at $z_0$ whereas the function $$\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}$$ may not be analytic at $z_0$ (it will be analytic at $z_0$ if and only if $f$ has a zero at $z_0$ of order at least $n+1$).

Comment: If $(z-z_0)^{(n+1)}=(z-3)^2$ what is a zero of order say 1 and/or 2?

Comment: I don't understand your question. My comment about zeroes refers to $f$, not $(z-z_0)^{n+1}$.

Comment: Okay if $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-z_O)^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{(z-3)^2}$ what can you say about the orders of the zeros of that function?

Comment: The function has no zeroes, but it has a pole of order two at $z = 3$.

Comment: Oh so the zeros are the variables that occur in the numerator?

Comment: A function $f$ has a zero at $w$ if $f(w) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy Integral Formula, $f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}} dz$.